# Get empty string not null in Ajax in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, form-data

I'm working with Ajax in Laravel, Whenever Ajax is called the input fields values(which are empty string) are converted into null value. But I want empty string in response. How can I get this?
I know I can map these values and convert/set null values to empty string but it is not efficient.

**My Ajax Code:**

```
$('#settingsForm').on('submit',(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.LoadingOverlay("show");
  const id = $('#id').val();
  const data = new FormData($('#settingsForm')[0]);
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:  "{{url('company/settings')}}"+'/'+id,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false, 
    data: data,
    beforeSend: ()=>{
      console.log(data);
    },
    success: (resp) => {
      if(resp.code == 200){
        toastr.success(resp.type,resp.msg);
      }else
        toastr.error(resp.type,resp.msg);
      $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
    }
  });
  $('#tableRow').show();
  $('#settingsDiv').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a getter for each of those value like this :

```
public function getNameAttribute($value){
    return $value ?? '';
}
```

Then using the `toArray()` or `toJson()` method your null values will be converted into an empty string